# Loading very large images with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ajax, image

I'm trying to load a very large image (from web app's perspective), around 10-20 MB with an AJAX call.

I use angular resource:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
.factory('Picture', function ($resource, DateUtils) {
    return $resource('api/pictures/search', {}, {
        'get': {
            method: 'GET',
            transformResponse: function (data) {
                data = angular.fromJson(data);
                return data;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and in return I get a response JSON where one of the fields contains Base64-encoded image, say something like this:

```
{title: "some title", picture: "<Base64-encoded image data>", ...}
```

Upon successful response I take `response.picture` and put it into an `<img>`:

```
<img ng-src="{{pictureSrc}}" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Picture">
```

like so:

```
Picture.get({id: resourceId}, function(response){
        $scope.pictureSrc = 'data:image/png;base64,' + response.picture;
    });
```

This approach works up till about 10MB, but as soon as size of the image increases past that, JSON deserialization fails.

If I change `Content-Type` of the response to `image/png`, and return only  image data, the app still fails, but somewhere in angular.js.

I realize my current approach isn't that flexible and it seems at this point I have to change the way this image fetching is done rather than fixing this one issue.

Hence my question: is there a sure way to get large images (up to 20MB) with an AJAX call using AngularJS?

**UPD**:
I'm running FF 42.0 and Chrome 45.0.2454.101 (64-bit), but it's expected to work on all major browsers as well as IE8 (that one is probably a topic of different conversation)

**UPD 2**:
*Clarification*: 
FF freezes if I return only image data, not JSON in my response. In case of JSON it says `JSON.parse: unterminated string at line 1 column 1572865 of the JSON data`.

Comment: What browser are you using?  Which version?

Comment: @Amy updated the question with browsers info.

Comment: @kooker What happens when you try to load up to 20MB of image? Does your browser crash? Or does it become unresponsive? Or are you getting any error in your browser console?

Comment: @krishnaxv It becomes unresponsive. FF shows error popup saying a script is taking too long and suggests I terminate it. If I don't it freezes. If I issue another requests it freezes my entire GUI.

Comment: @RyanVincent Unfortunately, downloading is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

> HTTP response (i.e. JSON in your case) has no size limit. **Browser
>   memory** is a limitation.

In your case object parsed from JSON response **consumes too much memory**. Hence, it becomes unresponsive. It's better you test with different data sizes and check whether your application works correctly.

Hope it helps!